# Form without submit button in Django

Tags: javascript, django

I see that forms without buttons are very popular (like [here](https://nomadlist.com/)). How to create a form that will be automatically submit for two different fields in Django, after the user selects the field (example 1) or type in the text and clicks something (it means completes typing) (example 2):

**1.) ChoiceField**

**forms.py**

```
class Search(forms.Form):
    field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MY_CHOICES)
```

**views.py**

```
if request.method == "GET":
    form = Search(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
    print('it's work')
```

**template.html**

```
<form method="GET">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
</form>
```

**2.) CharField**

**forms.py**

```
class Search(forms.Form):
    field = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
```

* *other files like above*

Comment: You set an `on_change` event on the field, and use AJAX requests.

Comment: Maybe this is from my little experience, but can you give an example of what it should look like AJAX requests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use jquery in your template like this:

```
$('#search_field').change(function(){
    $('#your_form').submit()
});
```

or when user click on something:

```
$('#something').click(function(){
    $('#your_form').submit()
});
```

Answer (score 14):

You may simply change **forms.py**:

```
class Search(forms.Form):
    field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MY_CHOICES,
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'submit();'}))
```

Nothing else to add, no jquery needed.

See also [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/).